# upgrade (software) RAID 1 capacity

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I am upgrading a software RAID 1 array (`/dev/md0`) from 2TB drives (`sda` and `sdb`) to 4TB (`sdc` and `sdd`). Straight forward; `ext3`, single partition, no MBR, no LVM. In the end, I would like to have two `/dev/mdX` devices, one with the original array, the other with the new array, both with the same data. From what I have gathered, there are two options:

**OPTION 1:**

1. backup the existing array
2. unmount existing array
3. insert a 4TB disk, and add it to the array

   ```
   mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdc1
   ```
4. fail one of the 2TB disks, and wait for the array to rebuild

   ```
   mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sda1
   mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sda1
   ```
5. insert the remaining 4TB disk, and add it to the array

   ```
   mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdd1
   ```
6. fail the remaining 2TB disk, wait for the array to rebuild

   ```
   mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sdb1
   mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sdb1
   ```
7. what do I do here to re-activate the 2TB array under a new `/dev/mdX` number? Can I simply type:

   ```
   mdadm create /dev/md1 --assume-clean /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
   ```

PROS: guaranteed mirroring of data, `mdX` device can be unmounted to avoid inconsistencies
CONS: have to sync twice (slow)

**OPTION 2:**

1. Create a new array with the 4TB disks:

   ```
   mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
   ```
2. Create filesystem on `/dev/md1` (same as used on `/dev/md0`)
3. Mount `/dev/md1`
4. Copy over the files using one of:

   ```
   tar -C /mnt/md0 --atime-preserve -clSf - . | tar -C /mnt/md1 -xvf -
   --or--
   rsync -avHhx --progress /mnt/md0 /mnt/md1
   ```

PROS: only have to sync once
CONS: no guarantee that the backup is exact (beyond the flags used for tar or rsync)

Which would be the preferred method, and why? Is there a better way[1]?

[1] I've read about using `dd`, but resizing `mdX` after copying seems to be an issue, and I would still need to create a new `/dev/mdX` for one of the arrays.

**UPDATE**
In the end I went with Option 2, as it is certainly the safest, and "cleanest". I also incorporated the comments/suggestions below, with some important caveats:

1. `fdisk` (currently) does not work reliably for partitions over 2TB, `parted` using a `gpt` partition table is recommended instead
2. hashing to verify rsync transfers is an excellent idea. Unfortunately `dd` is unsuitable since it reads the *whole* volume, zeros included. So by definition, hashes of 2TB and 4TB drives will be different. In addition, `dd` would have to read through all 2TB of data to provide a hash, and is unable to handle directories, which rules out checking individual critical folders. There are programs (`md5sumd` or `md5deep`) which hash directories recursively, but that kind of thoroughness didn't warrant the time required to read and hash 2TB of data. Instead, I whipped up a crude script to `diff` the output of `ls -lAR` for both volumes (luckily the block sizes were the same between them), and just hashed any files with different reported size. In the end, checking 2TB took only a couple of minutes.

Comment: if you need to make sure the files are the same you can use some hash for all the files. For me option one is interesting, but you can trouble to restore the things in case of failure. With option you have always 2 copies (original radi1 disks) of info

Comment: Hashing is a good option. Hash full drive. Something like                                dd if=/dev/devicename | md5 -hex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1** really isn't much of an option, after you've included the new disks into md0, you will still have to expand the ext3 filesystem, same as option 2 if you use dd. Except it takes longer, and many chances for things to go wrong.

If you must go down this route, you should do roughly the following:

Create raid partition (0xDA or 0xFD) with fdisk

```
fdisk /dev/sdc
fdisk /dev/sdd
```

Add the new disk to the array

```
mdadm --fail /dev/md0 /dev/sda1
mdadm --remove /dev/md0 /dev/sda1
mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1
```

Wait for resync to finish, then add another one

```
mdadm --fail /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1
mdadm --remove /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1
mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdd1
```

Wait for resync to finish, then grow md0. Do keep in mind that, you are vulnerable to disk failure during resync, which happens more often than most people think, because the disks are under maximum stress.

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=max --backup-file=/root/mnt/grow_md0.bak
mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm.conf
```

You don't need the backup-file option, but it protects you from unexpected failures, such as power cut during the operation. It needs to be on a different physical disk (reformat + remount one of the old disks or on a flash drive) or it defeats the purpose.

Give md0 a good checking first, then you can grow the ext3 fs

```
umount /mount/point-md0
fsck /dev/md0
resize2fs /dev/md0
mount -t ext3 /dev/md0 /mount/point-md0
```

The only potential advantage to this approach is, if you are willing to take some risks, you can do this without md0 going offline. resize2fs can actually grow your fs online (but not shrink), in which case you simply do without the umount-fsck-mount sequence.

To reactivate the old array, you have to use --assemble, --create will likely corrupt/destory existing data.

```
mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md1 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

---

**Option 2** is definitely the 'cleaner' solution. Far fewer chances for things to go wrong, because you always have at least one fully redundant array.

Create raid partition (0xDA or 0xFD) with fdisk

```
fdisk /dev/sdc
fdisk /dev/sdd
```

make md1

```
mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
```

Make a file system, and mount it

```
mkfs.ext3 -L some-label /dev/md1
mount -t ext3 /dev/md1 /mount/point-md1
```

Make md0 read-only, and rsync should guarantee file integrity, with the added bonus of cleaning up all of the fragmentation on the way.

```
mount -o remount,r /dev/md0 /mount/point-md0
rsync -axHAXS --delete --progress /mount/point-md0 /mount/point-md1
```

Update mdadm.conf

```
mdadm --detail --scan > /etc/mdadm.conf
```

And don't forget to update fstab!

---

Tangent to this subject matter:

- rsync will only copy the files, where mdadm resync will copy the 'empty' undefined spaces as well.
- There are few reasons to use RAID1 unless you are booting from it (which case you have to update the boot loader as well), RAID10 will give you the same protection but better performance if you have more than two physical disks in the array.
- LVM actually helps you with migration and backup. For instance in Option 2, instead of mounting it read-only before copying the files over, which is semi-offline for potentially a very long time, you can make a LVM snapshot, two pass rsync, and you can complete the migration with only a few seconds of downtime.
- If I can keep all four physical disks in the box, I would make three RAID partitions on each. A small RAID1 for /boot, decent size LVM+RAID10 for high performance parts, such as database, and LVM+RAID5/6 for storage.